# Can you put a NavigationPage inside a ContentPage?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a music player in Xamarin Forms. Now at the bottom of my page there always is a bar with the music player controls. Instead of always adding the  tag and creating a new PlayerBar in each view, I thought it would be useful to create a RootPage with the PlayerBar created once inside and above it a NavigationPage that spans the rest of the view.

[image]

In XAML it would look a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PodBase.Views"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PodBase.Controls"
             x:Class="PodBase.Views.RootPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <NavigationPage>
                <x:Arguments>
                    <views:MainPage/>
                </x:Arguments>
            </NavigationPage>
            <controls:PlayerControl/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

However when I try it out I get an error saying NavigationPage cannot be added to IGridList. Are there any other options I can use to work this out?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A `Page` can only be at the root. Inside you can have one `VisualElement` and within that `VisualElement` you can nest as many things as you like.

To achieve this kind of behavior, either inherit from the `NavigationPage` and add the player control at the bottom. Or, you will have to mimic your own navigation page behavior.